# Downloading a text file with PHP script removes break rows

Tags: php

So I have a text file to register emails of people who want to try demos. The document when I download via FTP has all emails separated by rows as intended but when I try to download it using the download page which is in the second part of the code, it joins all emails together with no break rows.

Code for writting in file

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) 
{ 
    if (validateEmail($_POST['email'])) 
    {   
        $file = 'documentos/emails.txt';
        $person = "Data: ".date("d/m/Y H:i:s")." - Email: ".xss_protect($_POST['email']).PHP_EOL;
        file_put_contents($file, $person, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }
    else
    {
        $erro = "Introduza um email válido!";
        unset($_POST['email']);

    }

}
?>
```

Code for file downloading

```
<?php
ob_clean();

$filename = strstr($_GET["file"], '/') . ".txt";
$filename = str_replace('/', '', $filename);
$file = $_GET["file"] .".txt";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($filename));   
header('Content-type: text/plain');          
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
flush();
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
while (!feof($fp))
{
    echo fread($fp, 65536);
    flush(); 
} 
fclose($fp); 
exit;
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not really clear from your description what is going on. But it might be that you are suffering from the fact that linebreaks are coded different on MS-Windows platforms and unixoid system which are typically used on server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your file is using the correct line breaks

```
echo str_replace("\n", "\r\n", fread($fp, 65536));
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It didn't accept '\r\n' only "\r\n".

Answer (score 0):

FTP may be configured to convert line endings for the destination system, this may be the case.
`PHP_EOL` may not be the end of line recognized on your system, try using a program like notepad++, or coding the new lines your system would recognise.  e.g. `\r\n`

Comment: I was using '\r\n' and changed it to PHP_EOL because I heard it will make different systems recognize the line breaks, but it doesn't work for downloading the file. It works for opening in filezilla though.

Comment: @Condward Obviously `PHP_EOL` uses the linebreak code ON SERVER SIDE! It cannot guess the client sides operating system! If in doubt always use the propper unixoid style linebreak: `\r\n` and not the MS-Windows version. Makes much more sense on the internet.